# Export word header table to excel powershell

Tags: powershell

please could you help me to get the header table from a word and export to excel document?

The target point is to have every field with his value to known all the fields and his values.

This is an example of the header:

[image]

and this is the target:

[image]

This is the code used, but returns me a text, and not a table:

```
$docPath = "C:\Users\Dummy\Desktop\"
$outputfile = "C:\Users\Dummy\Desktop\header_out.csv"
if(Test-Path -path $outputfile) { Remove-Item -path $outputfile }

$all_docs = Get-ChildItem $docPath -filter "n.docx"
$word = New-Object -comobject "Word.Application"
$word.Visible = $False
$all_items = @()

foreach ( $document in $all_docs)
{

 $item = New-Object System.Object
 $doc = $word.Documents.Open($document.FullName);
 
 $header = $doc.Sections.Item(1).Headers.Item(1).Range.Text

 
 $item | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Name -value $document.FullName
 $item | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Header -value $doc.Sections.Item(1).Headers.Item(1).Range.Text
 $all_items += $item
 $doc.Close()
 
}
$word.Quit()
Remove-Variable doc
Remove-Variable word
$all_items | Export-CSV  $outputfile
```

This is the result:

[image]

Thanks for your help and BR!!

Comment: I would examine `$header`, figure out what those non-printing characters are, and then try to use regex with capture groups to extract the data. Then I'd test it against a subset of your documents to be sure that it's going to pull the data right. Dimes to dollars they've modified that header more than once in the past and you'll need multiple patterns.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bacon Bits!!!, but i need to get the table that build the header as is, the target is to export to an excel and then manipulate as cell values, if there was a way to export the table of the header to excel would be great Thanks & BR!!.

Comment: You're outputting the `$all_items` to a CSV... That is a comma separated file, it has absolutely no formatting. You'll need to start learning how to use the Excel ComObject to get the results you want. With a CSV it's just impossible.